# need help resolving python error reported in ninja IDE

Tags: python-2.7

I'm working on some code cleanup (mainly pep8 work).  Ninja IDE is reporting "undefined name toolkit_channel_names" in the if statement.
Everything runs properly and there is no further indication as to why it is flagging this as an error.  Any thoughts?

```
global toolkit_channel_names

for channel in channels:
    if channel in toolkit_channel_names:
        err_msg = "Error message here"
```

Comment: Are you sure `toolkit_channel_names` is actually defined globally? Simply marking it as global in a function is not enough to define it.

Comment: Believe so.  I'm didn't write the code and fairly new to python.  There are no run time errors and this only shows this in the Ninja IDE.  Checked PyDev, PyCharm and Komodo.  All show no errors with this code.